# Issues running neo4j enterprise in HA mode

Tags: neo4j, node-neo4j

I am trying to setup 3slaves and 1master. Please look at this error below and why it gets timedout ?

```
$ neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use JDK 6.
Starting Neo4j Server...12:39:19,754 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
12:39:19,754 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
12:39:19,754 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/home/training/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.1/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml]
12:39:19,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@46165b7e - URL [jar:file:/home/training/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.1/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
12:39:20,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
12:39:20,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
12:39:20,134 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
12:39:20,196 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
12:39:20,341 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
12:39:20,341 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
12:39:20,343 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]
12:39:20,347 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@65d0d124 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

WARNING: not changing user
process [4490]... waiting for server to be ready................................................................................................................................................................................................................. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server failed to start, please check the logs for details.
If startup is blocked on a long recovery, use '/home/training/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.1/bin/neo4j start-no-wait' to give the startup more time.
training@node01:~$
```

Comment: "Failed to start within 120 seconds. Neo4j Server failed to start, please check the logs for details." -- have you checked the server log files?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant lines in your coord.conf and neo4j.properties?

Answer (score 1):

in the first error row: `You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use JDK 6.`
i also had the same issue, and had to install the newest java development kit. than it worked. but it was only a single server instance, maybe in your multiserver case it wont help.